# lapply: vector names as list names

Tags: r, lapply

When using `lapply()` over a vector, each element of the resulting list doesn't have a name, but only an index:

```r
library(dplyr)

vector = c("df1", "df2")

df1 = data.frame(a = rnorm(5), b = rnorm(5, sd = 1.1))
df2 = data.frame(a = rnorm(5), b = rnorm(5, sd = 1.1))

lapply(vector, function(x){
  
  x = get(x) %>%
    mutate(c = a+b)
})
#> [[1]]
#>            a          b          c
#> 1 -0.4098768  1.6712810  1.2614041
#> 2  0.7101722 -0.1025184  0.6076538
#> 3 -0.6696859  0.5690932 -0.1005928
#> 4  1.1642214 -0.4660378  0.6981836
#> 5 -0.5158280  1.4574039  0.9415759
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>             a         b          c
#> 1  0.91047848 -1.308707 -0.3982281
#> 2  1.87336493 -1.429567  0.4437977
#> 3  0.54171333  1.849589  2.3913028
#> 4 -0.02978158  2.500763  2.4709817
#> 5  1.49926589  1.602463  3.1017284
```

It does has names when applying over list:

```r
list = list(
  df1 = data.frame(a = rnorm(5), b = rnorm(5, sd = 1.1)),
  df2 = data.frame(a = rnorm(5), b = rnorm(5, sd = 1.1))
)

lapply(list, function(x){
  
  x = x %>%
    mutate(c = a+b)
})
#> $df1
#>            a          b           c
#> 1  0.8228400 -2.5232496 -1.70040963
#> 2  0.3890213 -0.4349408 -0.04591949
#> 3  0.5084719  1.4089123  1.91738415
#> 4  0.2533964 -0.7379615 -0.48456516
#> 5 -0.2474338  1.0520906  0.80465685
#> 
#> $df2
#>            a           b          c
#> 1  0.1376350 -1.32304077 -1.1854058
#> 2  0.1314702  1.14775210  1.2792223
#> 3  0.9757047 -1.24806193 -0.2723573
#> 4 -0.5118045  0.09277009 -0.4190344
#> 5 -0.1631715 -0.47573087 -0.6389024
```

Is there a **simple** way to use the vector elements as the resulting list names?

Comment: What about the `setNames` function, or just `names(result) <- ...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could name the vector, before lapply

```
vector = c("df1", "df2")
names(vector) <- vector  # <-- here

df1 = data.frame(a = rnorm(5), b = rnorm(5, sd = 1.1))
df2 = data.frame(a = rnorm(5), b = rnorm(5, sd = 1.1))


lapply(vector, function(x){

    x = get(x) %>%
    mutate(c = a+b)
})

# $df1
# a          b          c
# 1 -0.36671838  0.8733203  0.5066019
# 2 -0.05029296 -0.8823471 -0.9326401
# 3  0.54252815 -0.2087211  0.3338071
# 4 -1.16789527  0.2598863 -0.9080090
# 5 -0.80664672 -0.4968422 -1.3034889
# 
# $df2
# a          b          c
# 1  0.9042845  1.2978663  2.2021508
# 2 -0.3848533 -0.4563623 -0.8412156
# 3 -1.1681873  1.3224087  0.1542215
# 4  1.4872564 -2.0281272 -0.5408708
# 5 -0.2717229 -0.3780464 -0.6497694
```

Comment: Alternatively, `lapply(setNames(vector, vector), function(x) {
 get(x) %>%
  mutate(c = a+b)
})`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `get` on each list separately, you can use `mget` to get all the dataframes in a list with their names :

```
lapply(mget(vector), function(x) transform(x, c = a + b))

#$df1
#            a         b          c
#1 -0.60421251 2.4792735  1.8750610
#2  0.06163947 2.0295196  2.0911590
#3 -0.56318825 2.1496891  1.5865009
#4 -2.46292843 1.1641211 -1.2988073
#5 -1.05692446 0.4365812 -0.6203432

#$df2
#            a         b         c
#1 -0.33388039 0.6690467 0.3351663
#2  0.83637236 1.3321715 2.1685439
#3  0.05839826 0.1017032 0.1601015
#4 -0.20686296 0.8667050 0.6598420
#5  0.52682053 0.4629632 0.9897837
```

Comment: I'm not. It's just a reprex. I'm working with dbplyr + MySQL tables, so it looks like `x = tbl(con, paste(x)) %>% ...`

Comment: This can be written  `lapply(mget(vector), transform, c = a + b)
`

Comment: @AlbersonMiranda Sorry, your question is not clear to me. Can you update your post to include the code that you are using and remove the code that you are not using to avoid confusion?

Comment: @RonakShah wouldn't be reproducible. But i upvoted your answer aswell since it does answer what was proposed in the reprex :)

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(mget(vector), ~ .x %>%
                        mutate(c = a + b))
```